# Trying to understand the energy-momentum tensor from the Polyakov action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, variational-calculus

I am reading the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201124. The Polyakov action is defined as

$$S_{str} =  \int d^2\zeta (-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g^{ab}\partial_aX^\mu \partial_bX_\mu).$$

I am trying to understand the following expression for the symmetric energy-momentum tensor $T_{ab}$:

$$T_{ab} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_{str}}{\delta g^{ab}}$$
$$= -\partial_aX^\mu \partial_bX_\mu + \frac{1}{2}g_{ab}g^{cd}\partial_cX^\mu \partial_dX_\mu$$

I have two questions.

1. Is the first equality just a definition?
2. Also, I understand how the first term in the second equality comes about but how does one get the term $\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}g^{cd}\partial_cX^\mu \partial_dX_\mu$?

Comment: Look up the Hilbert stress-energy tensor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor

Answer (score 3):

As alexarvanitakis has already said the answer to your first question is yes. When varying the action with respect to the metric you obtain the energy-momentum tensor, namely

$\begin{equation}
T_{\alpha \beta} = - \frac{2}{T} \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\alpha \beta}}
\end{equation}$

So, we have

$\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\alpha \beta}} \delta g^{\alpha \beta} = - \frac{T}{2} \int d^2 \zeta \sqrt{-g} ~ T_{\alpha \beta} ~ \delta g^{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}$

And now let's perform the computations to find the terms. 
The variation is

$\begin{equation}
\delta S = - \frac{T}{2} \int d^2 \zeta \left(\delta \sqrt{-g}~ g^{\alpha \beta} ~ \partial_{\alpha} X \cdot ~ \partial_{\beta} X + \sqrt{-g} ~ \delta g^{\alpha \beta} ~ \partial_{\alpha} X \cdot ~\partial_{\beta} X   \right)
\end{equation}$

We have to use the standard formulae for the metric variations (you can find these in G.R, string theory textbooks, etc)

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\delta g &= - g ~ g_{\alpha \beta} ~ \delta g^{\alpha \beta} \\
\delta \sqrt{-g} &= - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} ~ g_{\alpha \beta} ~ \delta^{\alpha \beta}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

for the above $\delta S$. This yields

$\begin{equation}
\delta S = -\frac{T}{2} \int d^2 \zeta ~ \sqrt{-g} ~ \delta g^{\alpha \beta} ~ \left( -\frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha \beta} g^{\gamma \delta} ~ \partial_{\gamma} X \cdot \partial_{\delta} X + \partial_{\alpha} X \cdot \partial_{\beta} X   \right) = 0
\end{equation}$

I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes.
2) The second term comes from the variation of $\sqrt{\det g}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to vary the $\sqrt{det\ g}$ term.